# How to get duration of active storage video attachment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails application, I have a model with a video as an attachment. I would like to display how long the video is (duration), but can't seem to figure out what method or what attributes to call on the blob to get that information.

Ideally, it would be something like this:

```
Lecture.video.blob.duration
```

But that doesn't exist. I can't seem to find it in the documentation; perhaps I'm just looking in the wrong places.

I appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

** The documentation link below notes that the [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org) library is required to use the VideoAnalyzer. This can be installed via homebrew with `$ brew install ffmpeg`

Here's a link to [VideoAnalyzer](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/96f142ae76b04f5ffe6e4c33550f5b04739f4f56/activestorage/lib/active_storage/analyzer/video_analyzer.rb#L14) documentation.

Essentially, you can do something like...

```
ActiveStorage::Analyzer::VideoAnalyzer.new(@lecture.video.blob).metadata[:duration]
```

Answer (score 4):

You were almost there:

```
Lecture.video.blob.metadata.fetch(:duration, nil)
```

Comment: Without the `blob` also works for me (Rails 6.1) `Lecture.video.metadata`

Comment: Be sure to run the `Lecture.video.analyze` first and I think you need `FFmpeg` installed in your system